# drupal7- user/edit/1 getting access denied permission for admin and member? Not able to edit the personal details

Tags: drupal-7

[edit permission denied for admin for all roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lePEa.png)[Access Denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/po0xU.png)

Please Suggest me ideas to solve my issue

Comment: i am not sure, but maybe for security reasons the site owner (user with id 1) is the only one allowed to edit this profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper link must be {your_domain}/user/{uid}/edit

Thanks

Comment: When i click the url only i am getting acess denied. For reference only i attached the screenshot above. So suggest me to solve this problem

Comment: Have you given "Administer users " permission to admin role.